# Trying to create a Printing Calculator program in Python, program outputs 0 infinitely

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, calculator, msvcrt

I'm trying to make this printing calculator program in Python 2.7.8, but whenever I run it, it outputs this:

```
0
0
0
0
```

And so on. It does this infinitely and never stops. I would really appreciate any help. Here is my code. Thanks!

```
import msvcrt             # Windows only!
def getch():  
    return msvcrt.getch()
def putch(ch):
    msvcrt.putch(ch)

total     = 0
pendingOp = 0
print "*** Calculator ***" 
while True:
    ch = getch()
    if ch == "q": break      # quit
    if ch == "c":            # clear the display
        total = 0            
        pendingOp = 0
    elif ch == "a" or "s" or "m" or "d":  # add, subtract, multiply, divide
        pendingOp = ch       
    elif (ch >= "0" and ch <= "9"):
        newNumber = int(ch)
        if pendingOp == 0:  
            total = newNumber
        else:            
            if   pendingOp == "a": total = total + newNumber
            elif pendingOp == "s": total = total - newNumber
            elif pendingOp == "m": total = total * newNumber
            elif pendingOp == "d": total = total / newNumber
            pendingOp = 0
    print total
```

Comment: does hitting q not work?

Comment: Hitting q does not work. Just keeps outputting 0.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why use `msvcrt` to get a character? Why not just use `input`? Also, if you step through the code using `pdb`, what does `ch` equal after you input `q`? Is it actually `q`?

Comment: If I print ch, it outputs this character: ÿ

The same way it does with the 0 as before infinitely

Comment: If I use msvcrt.getch().decode('ASCII') I get a UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: How do you set the language environment of your windows machine?

Comment: My language is set to English (US) if thats what you mean...

Comment: Is it outputting an endless stream of 0 lines without waiting for you to type anything, or is it just outputting one line for each character you type?

Comment: Also, how are you running the program? Are you in a cmd ("DOS prompt") window and typing `python myscript.py`, or are you running it in some other way (which might not get it connected to the console)?

Comment: It is outputting an endless stream of 0 lines without waiting for me to type anything. I am running it through the shell in the Python IDLE.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that, for one reason or another, you don't have a console.

Python's `msvcrt.getch` is a thin wrapper around the MSVCRT function [`_getch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/078sfkak.aspx). While the docs there say "there is no error return", that isn't really true. If there is no console for the app, these functions return immediately, returning -1 (cast to the appropriate type, which means you get `'\xff'` for `getch` and `u'\uffff'` for `getwch`—which is exactly what you're seeing).

So, why would there be no console?

The most common reason is that you're running the app in some GUI IDE, like IDLE or PyWin, instead of from the cmd shell (aka "DOS prompt"). You can't use `msvcrt` in IDLE.*

There are other possibilities, like explicitly closing or detaching from the console, but I doubt those are relevant here.

So, what *can* you do?

Well, if you're using IDLE, it's actually simulating command-line input on top of a Tkinter GUI. That simulation doesn't provide any way to get input a character at a time, only a line at a time. So, you could just use `raw_input` instead of `msvcrt.getch` here.

You could theoretically hook the IDLE simulated input, but that would be a lot more work than just, say, building your own Tkinter GUI (or Qt or Win32 or whatever GUI) for your app, for a lot less benefit.

Or, alternatively, you can stop running the program in IDLE. Open a cmd window and run the program with `python myscript.py` (or `C:\Python27\python D:\mystuff\myscript.py`, or whatever). If you don't know how to use the shell on Windows, this is a good time to learn.

---

<sub>* Well, you can call the Windows API functions to explicitly allocate a console, via `ctypes` or `win32api`. But if you do that, it's going to pop up a separate cmd shell window for you to type into anyway, it's still not going to affect IDLE's input.</sub>

Comment: Ok, now I think we're getting somewhere... Now when I open the program using cmd, whenever I type a character it outputs 0. If it type q then it does quit, but anything else and it just outputs 0.

Comment: I just tried using raw_input instead, but it still gives me an endless stream of 0 lines. I really appreciate you trying to help me!

Comment: Yes, I think abarnert has gotten you past a very tricky one, probably the rest is a more basic programming bug.

Comment: @JohnHillman: Can we see your code with `raw_input`? Either tack it onto the end of your question, or create a new question. Calling `raw_input()` should definitely block until you hit Enter, even in IDLE, while `msvcrt.getch()` should immediately return 255/65535. (Maybe "should" is the wrong word; this should never happen according to the docs, it would probably be a better design if it raised an exception instead of casting the -1, but… it always _has_ behaved like this.)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the wonderful world of converting between different string encodings. That particular API returns a byte string which is different from Python's normal string UTF encoding, and the two won't compare.  Try for example `if ch == b'q'`.

Another solution is to get the wide characters directly:

```
def getch():
    return msvcrt.getwch()
```

Of some question to me is that Ctrl-C is returned (on Windows, obviously), even though the API documentation for my python says it shouldn't be.

Update:

abarnert's answer seems to be the root cause.  I'm leaving this answer because string encoding issues causes the same symptoms on Python 3 running in the console, and in general are a cause of similarly interesting headaches.

Comment: BTW, after this you only really have one more big bug to work out, and I think you'll get it pretty fast.  Nice!

Comment: When I use your return msvcrt.getwch() it does the same thing. Thanks for your response though!

Comment: @JohnHillman: What do you mean "does the same thing"? Can you `print repr(ch), ord(ch)` to see what it's actually returning? Because 255 (`'ÿ'`) is a fishy thing to be returning from an 8-bit function…

Comment: By "Does the same thing" I mean that it still infinitely outputs 0. If I print repr(ch), ord(ch) then it prints u'\uffff' 65535 infinitely.

Comment: @PeterM: The question is for Python 2.7, so `b'q'` is the same thing as `'q'`, and `b'q' == u'q'` will compare true, so most of this answer is wrong. The suggestion for `getwch()` is still a good idea, but I don't think it's his problem.

Comment: @JohnHillman: OK, if you get 255 from `getch` and 65535 from `getwch`, then this is definitely an error. Although the docs say "there is no error return", this is exactly what happens if you don't have a console. Please see my last comment on the question.

Comment: @abarnet Indeed, I am on Python 3 and I don't have 2.7 on any windows machines at the moment.  Interesting that the symptoms are identical (for drastically different causes)!

Comment: @PeterM: Well, it's really the same reason; calling the 8-bit version of `getch` returns an 8-bit string in the OEM charset, whether Python turns that into a `str` or a `bytes`, and likewise for the 16-bit version (except that 3.3+ works a little better with non-BMP characters… making it harder to debug when it doesn't…).

Comment: @abarnet Oh, I meant string encodings vs non-console both causing the same symptom.  When I was adding parens to the print statements I should have remembered that the byte PEP was a 3.0 thing.